# Given a moment generating function, find $E[(5/6)^x]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**X is a random variable with moment generating function $m_x(t) = (0.7 + 0.3e^t)^{20}$**

**a) Find $P(X \lt 9 | X \gt 3)$**

**b) Find $E[\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^X]$**

*What I have done so far:*

Given that mgf form, this random variable follows a binomial distribution $(q - pe^t)^n$ so p = 0.3, and n =20. So X~$B(20, 0.3)$

a) $P(X \lt 9 | X \gt 3) = \left(\frac{P(X \lt 9 \cap X \gt 3)}{P(X \gt 3)}\right) = \left(\frac{P(X = 4) + ... +P(X=8)}{1 - P(X \le 3)}\right)$

I can do the rest of this by brute force given the binomial distribution formula of:

$P(Y=y) = (nCy)P^y(1-p)^{n-y}$ where $n = 20$ in this case

So when I expand out the previous equation, I get $\approx 0.8730767$

I'm not sure if this is correct, but that is the work I have so far.

b) This part is where I am stuck. I have been having difficulties finding modified expected values when given a moment generating function. I'm not even really sure how to start this one yet. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding b), note that $(5/6)^X = e^{X \log(5/6)}$ and think about the definition of the moment generating function.

Comment: Hmm, so in that case, I should start by letting $E[\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^X] = E(e^{xln\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)})$. And since $m_y(t) = E(e^{ty}) = \sum_{y=0}^n e^{ty}p(y)$, would I just let $t=ln(5/6)$ and continue by definition? Something like $\sum_{x=0}^n e^{xln(5/6)}p(x) = \sum_{x=0}^n e^{xln(5/6)}(nCx)(1-p)^{n-x}p^x = \sum_{x=0}^n (nCx)(1-p)^{n-x}(pe^{ln(5/6)})^x$. Then I could use the binomial formula to get $((1-p) + pe^{ln(5/6)})^n = (q + pe^{ln(5/6)})^{20}$ since $n=20$ and $q=1-p$. Or am I still going in the wrong direction with this?

Comment: @Doadle You already have the function $m_x(t)$, you don't need to re-compute it.